# Ref - Parameters - Stack or Heap

Tags: c#

Its only a theoretical question, but I can't get a good answer:

If I pass a parameter by `ref`, the object itself is passed and not a copy.

Here is what confuses me: As far as I know, each method has its own stack frame - memory, which they can't leave. So does that mean a ref - Object gets packed on the Heap and there is a reference to this parameter, or does the method go into the stack of the calling method and works there?

I'm sorry if my question is confusing, I basically would like to know how a ref type is saved and what impact it has.

Edith:
I think I didnt make myself clear. I understand the concept of value and refence types. To make it easier, I try to explain it just by a value type, lets say Int:

Procedure 1 calls Prodecure 2 by passing an Int ByVal. This int has its own memory on the Stack of Prodecure 2, which means, altering this value in P2 doesnt change the Value in P1, since this 2 values are saved in each Stack once.

Now the same with byref: Prodecure 2 doesnt save a Copy of Int, but has access to this value directly. There are (in my Oppinion) two possibilies to make this work:

1. The int gets packed on the Heap, and there are in fact 2 Pointers on
   this Int, but since its now on the Heap, the value changes are seen
   on both Prodecures.
2. P2 has kindahow access to the Stack of P1, which
   I thought, is not possible, since this would mean, the
   Stack-lifetime is not setted in Stone.

Does this make it more clear what I mean?

Comment: This may help you : http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: each method has its own stack  ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Well, a stack frame at least, not it's own stack.

Comment: *The object itself* is not passed, *a reference to the object* is passed. By value. On the stack or in a register or through some other implementation detail.

Comment: with ref you are passing the memory address of the parameter and not the actual parameter.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi not _a_ reference , but the _same_ reference. (using ref)

Comment: @Royi, nope, *a* reference IMHO. A reference is a value (stored somewhere) that contains the address of the instance. You can have multiple instances of such values, all containing the same address (referencing the same instance).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I will agree with Royi, with ref you actually pass the same reference and not a different one.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Here it's from c# via CLR http://i.stack.imgur.com/BS1gN.jpg

Comment: @Royi, I think we're not speaking of the same thing. I'm no Eric Lippert, but here goes: a reference is a memory cell that contains the address of another memory cell. There can be several cells that contain the same address (referencing the same object). Therefore, *a* reference, not *the* reference, but *the* address, not *an* address.

Comment: @Rahul No, actually.  When you pass a reference by `ref` you're passing a reference to a reference.  This is analogous to a pointer to a pointer.  You're not passing a copy of the same reference, that would be passing the reference by value.

Comment: @Servy, not clear. Say, my object `obj` is in Heap address `0xxab`. then when you pass by ref, you actually passing the same address .. right? (OR) it passes another reference say `0xxdm` which pointing to `0xxab`.

Comment: @Rahul No, you're not.  You're passing an address to the location where the `obj` variable resides, that is holding onto the address that is pointing to some location in the heap.  If you passed the reference type *by value* then you would just be passing a copy of the reference to that heap location.

Comment: @Servy, that means it's a 2 level indirection. I was thinking we directly pass the memory address and not another level of indirection.

Comment: @Servy so here http://i.stack.imgur.com/5nn1N.jpg the function which has ref parameter would actually take `0xhh1` and not `0xab123` ... ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes.  As I said from the start, passing a reference by reference is passing a reference to where the reference is stored, it is not copying the value of the reference.  You copy the value of the reference when you pass it by value.

Comment: I hope the drawing made it clearer

Comment: Yes, indeed it has. Now, what @Servy saying, makes sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The parameter that is passed is an address to some object.  That reference is passed on the stack, along with all other parameters to the method.

The actual object itself lives wherever it lived before you called the method.  That could be in the stack, it could be in the heap, it doesn't matter.  The act of passing an object by reference does not result in it being moved in memory, from say the stack to the heap, or from the heap to the stack.

Comment: I was under the impression that the object *can* move in memory (unless pinned), and the reference will follow somehow (direct update or double indirection). Otherwise the GC would have a hard time doing its job as soon as references to objects exist.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's speaking to a somewhat different layer of abstraction.  (From the point of view of any object with a reference to something in the heap, it's not moving at all, because all of their references are always going to the same place.  That the GC hits a different block of memory to resolve the address is inside a different black box.)  Any in any case that's not moving because the object is passed by reference, that's an object moving because the GC is doing a collection.  My main point here is that, unlike say a closure, the variable is not hoisted when passed by `ref`.

Comment: I believe unless we explicitly pinn it with `fixed` statement. But by `fixed` we make sure that while GC at work the object should stay where it is (not movable). Otherwise, just by passing the reference; yes, object doesn't move anywhere.

Comment: @Servy, I see. I did fail to infer this from your answer, maybe mentioning captures would help making what you mean by *move* clearer.

Comment: I dont understand how an object doesnt move if GC does compacting phase

Comment: @RoyiNamir I never said it doesn't.  I said the act of passing it by reference doesn't move it, not that it cannot be moved by some entirely separate effect on it, such as a GC compaction.  The question is implying that an object on the stack would be moved to the heap by the act of being passed by reference.  This is not the case, it stays wherever it is.

Comment: +1. Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) which states that `ref` does not cause boxing/unboxing of value types. This logically means that value types passed by `ref` *must* remain on *a* stack if they were originally allocated as stack variables, so the logical assumption would be that it remains on the stack where it was allocated.

Comment: @AdamRobinson No, they are not *forced* to remain on the stack. They remain *wherever they were before you passed them by reference*.  Maybe that was on the stack, maybe it was on the heap, who knows.  It doesn't matter.  The point is that wherever it is, it stays there, and a new reference to wherever that location is is created, that reference is passed to the method, and that reference is used to modify the *variable* (not the *value* of the variable) within the method body.

Comment: @Servy: Correct; I omitted part of my comment and have edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought its not possible for a Stackframe to leave itself to connect to another Stackframe, but it seems like I was wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Although Servy has correctly answered the question, it seems there's an awful lot of confusion as to what the difference is between passing a parameter with `ref` and passing the reference of the object by value.  For that reason, I think it's worth providing a short illustration.

Assume the following simple class:

```
class Player
{
    public Player(int health)
    {
        Health = health;
    }
    public int Health { get; set; }
}
```

We can now test updating the properties of the object and also changing the reference itself:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Player player = new Player(100);
    Console.WriteLine(player.Health);

    ChangeHealth(player);
    Console.WriteLine(player.Health);
    ChangeHealthByRef(ref player);
    Console.WriteLine(player.Health);

    ChangePlayer(player);
    Console.WriteLine(player.Health);
    ChangePlayerByRef(ref player);
    Console.WriteLine(player.Health);
}

static void ChangeHealth(Player player)
{
    player.Health = 80;
}

static void ChangeHealthByRef(ref Player player)
{
    player.Health = 60;
}

static void ChangePlayer(Player player)
{
    player = new Player(40);
}

static void ChangePlayerByRef(ref Player player)
{
    player = new Player(20);
}
```

Output:

```
100
80
60
60
20
```

`ChangeHealth` successfully modifies the `Health` property of the `player` object.
`ChangeHealthByRef` also successfully modifies the `Health` property of the `player` object. So you can see, in both calls, the object to which `player` refers, can be modified, in spite of `ChangeHealth` using a copy of the reference.

Now, here's the part where I think people are getting confused:

`ChangePlayer` creates a new `Player` object which modifies the *copy of the reference passed in*.  That means the change *does not* reflect in the calling code (i.e. `Health` still = 60).
`ChangePlayerByRef` also creates a new `Player` object but, this time, it's *modifying the reference directly*, which means the change *does* reflect in the calling code (i.e. `Health` = 20).