# Returning a private field by ref from a get only property

Tags: c#

I have been messing around with structs. I have looked for an example of this but have not found anything.

```
struct TransformComponent 
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}

class Foo 
{
    private TransformComponent _transform;

    public ref TransformComponent Transform
    {
        get { return ref _transform; }
    }
}

class Bar
{
    Foo testFoo = new Foo;

    void TestMethod()
    {
        testFoo.Transform.X = 5;
    }
}
```

This compiles and works as you would assume it does.

Is there something wrong with doing this that I am not seeing?

The reason why this is interesting to me is that as TransformComponent being a Value Type rather than a Reference Type it would be stored in memory next to the Foo object correct? Rather than possibly somewhere else in memory if it was a Reference Type?

Edit:

After reading the post I realize my question might not have been clear.

Will the _transform be stored next to the Foo object in memory since it is a Value Type and a field of the class?

Edit 2:

Reading the answer, it is clear that the _transform Member is getting allocated along side the Foo instance on the Heap.

If I am not mistaken, I am removing one level of address reference by doing it this way correct?

If I switched TransformComponent to a Reference Type the _transform Member would be a reference to the object allocated in the Heap rather than a reference to the Value itself correct?

Edit 3:

I need to look into how things are allocated more. Thank you to everyone who participated, for your time.

Comment: is it valid because see code first time , i.e. ref at property level and if it does what is need of it

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you are tying to say

Comment: Is compiler compiling this code ??

Comment: Yes, and it is changing the X value correctly.

Comment: ok what is question , where it get stored ??

Comment: Will the _transform field be stored in memory next to the Foo object as it is a Value Type?

Comment: Yes, I guess I wasn't quite as clear with the question as I should have been.

Comment: It's not "next to" the Foo object - it's *part of* the Foo object.

Comment: I see. And if it was a Reference Type instead of a Value Type would that make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as `Transform` is part of Class `Foo`, it get stored on Heap only as it part of userdefined type clas i.e. reference type.

When you mark it as `Ref` that means you are passing it address not object and what every change made to it will change value stored on the given address.

---

If you have declared value type in the method then it will get stored on stack, and that adddress will be pass in ref.

So point is when you mark variable as `Ref` it doesnt allocate memory on heap , it will remain where it is (i.e. on heap/stack). `Ref` only tells that you are passing address so change made to variable will reflect to adress.

this might help : [Reference type modification vs change of reference](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2016/02/reference-type-modification-vs-change.html)

Comment: Ah, okay I understand what you mean. Thank you. Secondary question, if Transform was a Reference Type would the _transform member be stored the same way? Or would it get its own address on the heap with a "pointer" to that address being stored along with the allocated instance of Foo?

Comment: @Spool - _transform get stored on heap as it backup private variable of property , with you foo class as it part of it ...i provide info in my answer ...

Comment: Right, I understood that from your answer. Thank you. I'm only using the ref in the Property for access convince of the _transform members.

Comment: @Spool - you can check this also helps you to understand it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353070/ref-parameters-stack-or-heap

Comment: Yes, I understand how it works when you pass a Value by ref to a Method as a parameter. I was more concerned with where it gets allocated, as you mentioned it gets allocated on the heap with the Foo instance. But if TransformComponent was a Reference Type rather than a Value Type. Would it be allocated in the same way or would it be allocated in its own location on the heap with a reference to the address in the Foo instance rather than the value itself.

Comment: By doing it this way with the Value Type if I am not mistaken I am removing one level of address reference. As when you access the TransformComponent Property you are getting a reference to the value of the Value rather than another reference if it were a Reference Type.

Comment: @Spool - by doing ref you are directly dealing with address of that variable

Comment: Yes, which is with the Foo Instance on the Heap. If the _transform Member was a Reference Type rather than a Value Type it would be yet another reference to the address rather than the address itself correct?

Comment: @Spool - yes , but if it is reference type its part of main type foo, so as per theory it will get removed by garbage collector when foo is not reference by any one

Comment: Ohhh, okay. I understand. Thank you for your time.